# Want to Ignore Comma(,) in ADF as delimiter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Have text tab delimited file which I'm converting into csv in ADF
In which, some field having comma separated values ( Don't want to split into columns) -> want to treat it as single column
But in ADF trying to separate those values into multiple column
Although, I have set a delimiter as "TAB(\t)", still ADF taking Comma and tab both as delimiter
why?

[image: tab delimited file ex]

As you can see in the above Ex,
I want to split this on basis of '\t' delimiter but ADF considering 'tab' as well as 'comma' as a delimiter(**Want to treat [pp,aa] as single value/column)**

Any solution? plz let me know.
Thank you
Attaching ADF conf as well.
[image: ADF CONF]

Answer (score 2):

Set the quote character to a **single character** instead of "No quote character" in source and sink datasets.

I tried with the sample and was able to get the data as expected.

Source:

[image]

Source Dataset:

[image]

Sink Dataset:

[image]

output:

[image]

Reference - [Dataset Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties)

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **quoteChar** | The single character to quote column values if it contains column delimiter. The default value is **double quotes** `"`. |
| **escapeChar** | The single character to escape quotes inside a quoted value. The default value is **backslash `\`**. |